# how to return a data frame after subsetting its columns with NAs removed

Tags: database

I'm working on a problem from coursera and seem to get lost at the end where I have to extract both selected columns and return a data frame, there is a link to a similar problem at ([Empty rows in list as NA values in data.frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773348/empty-rows-in-list-as-na-values-in-data-frame-in-r))

```
rankall <- function(outcome, num = 'best'){
      data<- read.csv('outcome-of-care-measures.csv', colClasses = 'character')
      if(!outcome %in% c('heart attack', 'heart failure', 'penumonia')){
         stop('invalid outcome')
    }
    states <- sort(unique(state))
    for (i in 1:length(state)){
         statedata <- data[data$State == state[i], ]
         if(outcome == 'heart attack'){
             index <- as.numeric(statedata[,11])
    }    else if(outcome == 'heart failure'){
             index <- as.numeric(statedata[,17])
    }    else if(outcome == 'pneumonia'){
             index <- as.numeric(statedata[,23])
    }
    #sort by mortality rate and hospital name
    sorteddata <- data[order(data[,index],data$Hospital.Name, na.rm = TRUE)]
    #rank by state
     staterank <- function(state){
         hospital_state <- subset(sorteddata, State == state)
    }
        #choose rows at each num value, this where I get stuck 
         if(!is.numeric(num)){
             if(num == 'best'){
                 num <- 1}
             else if(num == 'worst'){
                 num <- length(hospital_state)}
              }
         hospital_state[num]
         }
```

Comment: in reference to the above, I basically am stuck at the point of bringing all the subsets together in the final data frame. thank you very much.

Comment: @micah: I originally tried a different approach and Rstudio 's error read, can't find the object state. For this approach, I don't know how to return the rows that are subsetted with the correct num, So, I haven't even tried running it through R this time,

Comment: @micah: here is again what Rstudio returns: source('rankall.R')
> head(rankall('heart attack', 20),10)
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : object 'state' not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In rankall("heart attack", 20) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In rankall("heart attack", 20) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In rankall("heart attack", 20) : NAs introduced by coercion
Called from: rankall("heart attack", 20)

Comment: @micah: source('rankall.R')
> head(rankall('heart attack', 20),10)
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : object 'state' not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In rankall("heart attack", 20) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In rankall("heart attack", 20) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In rankall("heart attack", 20) : NAs introduced by coercion
Called from: rankall("heart attack", 20)